# How to display two WFS layers at the same time from MapServer?

Tags: openlayers, wfs, mapserver

I'm using OpenLayers, I have two WFS vector layers. When I show only one layer, it works. But doesn't work when I'm trying to show two WFS layers at the same time.

How to show two WFS layers together?

Comment: What happens if you request two feature types in the same WFS request, something like: `http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/ows?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typename=GBR_BGS_625k_SLT,UKCoShelf_BGS_1M_SBS&`